# Check if a value from one column is present inside a list in a different column

Tags: r, search, vector, nested

In a dataframe I would like to test if a value in a column is present in a second column. However, the second column is a list column containing a repeated vector as shown below:

```
library(tidyverse)

numbers.col <- c(1,2,3)

letters.col <- c("a", "b", "c")

search.for <- list("a","b")

df <- data.frame(numbers.col, letters.col)

df$search.for <- list(search.for)

df
```

This results in:

```
  numbers.col letters.col search.for
1           1           a       a, b
2           2           b       a, b
3           3           c       a, b
```

Trying to search. If it worked, I would have "Ok" for rows 1 and 2 and "Nok" for row 3 (result column).

```
mutate(df, result = if_else(df$letters.col %in% df$search.for, "Ok", "Nok"))

  numbers.col letters.col search.for result
1           1           a       a, b    Nok
2           2           b       a, b    Nok
3           3           c       a, b    Nok
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: `df %>% mutate(result = if_else(letters.col %in% unlist(search.for), "Ok", "Nok"))`

Comment: @HoelR's code works because all of `search.for` is invariant. If one row is different, it will likely not be true. (If it's always identical, then that code is the best, though I might include `unique(unlist(search.for))`.)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I'll stick to the one from @HoelR as it´s the easiest for me to understand right now, but I will study the others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `map2_chr` to map the two vectors to a string:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  mutate(result = map2_chr(letters.col, search.for, 
                           ~if_else(.x %in% .y, "Ok", "Nok")))
#>   numbers.col letters.col search.for result
#> 1           1           a       a, b     Ok
#> 2           2           b       a, b     Ok
#> 3           3           c       a, b    Nok
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
> transform(df, result = c("Nok", "Ok")[1 + mapply(`%in%`, letters.col, search.for)])
  numbers.col letters.col search.for result
1           1           a       a, b     Ok
2           2           b       a, b     Ok
3           3           c       a, b    Nok
```